# How to create an IPA file (non-payload folder method)

Tags: applications, xcode, archive, ios

I'm trying to create an iOS IPA file using Xcode. I have archived it (Product → Archive) and it is visible under my archives (Window → Organiser), but Xcode says I can't Export it unless I have an Apple Developer Licence.

[image]

Is there any way to create a proper IPA of this (not by placing the .app into a folder named payload, zipping that folder, and then renaming the .zip to .ipa)?

When I try to do what is suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26929524/6995250), this happens:

```
$ cd ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2019-05-07 
$ xcodebuild -exportArchive -exportFormat ipa -archivePath g0blinpreRC3.xcarchive -exportPath ~/Desktop/Jailbreak/iOS\ 10/g0blin_preRC3.ipa

xcodebuild: error: invalid option '-exportFormat'
```

Comment: See if this answers your query: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26929524/6995250

Comment: @NimeshNeema I added to my question what happens when I try that

Comment: Remember also that an IPA file can be created by zipping the file and changing the extension. This will not create an installable app, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't create an ipa file without an Apple Developer Account.

You can create a free developer account and sign the app with a development certificate.  You won't be allowed to distribute the app to anyone but you can use it on your own devices.

An overview of the different types of memberships are available [here](https://developer.apple.com/support/compare-memberships/).

Comment: I have a free developer account, and the app has been signed by it

Comment: You question indicates you don't have a Developer account: ‘Xcode says I can't export it unless I have an Apple Developer License'.

Comment: I don't have a paid Apple Developer License (for distribution or the appstore), but I have macOS and iOS Development licences